# Keep the hover state on the last clicked menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I have added a nice (`jquery` + `css`) navigation menu to my website, but there's a small problem. When I click on a menu item, the light blue box jumps back to the first item, and I would like the box to stay on the clicked item, but I have no clue how to make it happen.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Stylock/ta8g4/

In that example, it actually works how I want, but on my website it doesn't work for some reason. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: its working fine for me stayed on the clicked item

Comment: I assume it's because you're switching pages on your real website, right? And the new page initializes the menu slider again...

Comment: As it works in the fiddle, please add the code from your website.

Comment: If it doesn't work on your website, please provide a link to it

Comment: Is it navigating to a new page when you click it in the site?
If it reloads the page all the javascript will rerun from scratch and you'll lose the state

Comment: It does navigate me to a new page and I think that is the problem. How do I make it so it doesn't initialize the menu slider?

Comment: you should then add the class in the html generated with the serverside language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the item like .selected

And in your css you apply the same style to the .selected than the :hover

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Or you cloud also modify the css using jQuery. But the first solution is more flexible.

Edit: Use the callback function to add/remove class, after your effect

Comment: Here it doesn't work on the fiddle (Chrome under linux(ubuntu))

Comment: I might try this solution. I'm curious though why jsfiddle doesn't work on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a solution to the right direction:
Onclick check if the menu already has a classname to get the background changed
remove that class from there
Add the class where you clicked
some minor css changes are needed and u will have solved it

have a great day

Comment: I'm a total newbie. It would take me quite a while to figure out how to do that stuff.

Comment: I think by taking time it's better so you would better understand

I'll help you just follow the following links:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

$('.ClassYouClicked').on('click', function(){
// remove the class previously added
// add the class on your current item you clicked (hint $(this)  )
})

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can add a class when other page loads like to add on all pages like 
this is bad one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).load(function () {
        $("#index").toggleClass("highlight");

    });


    $(window).unload(function () {
        $("#index").toggleClass("highlight");
    });

</script>
```

site i used this at http://www.hoteloperaindia.com/

or like this short one to add this to master page

```
 <script>
        $(function () {
            var loc = window.location.href; // returns the full URL
            if (location.pathname == "/")  {
                $('#home').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/index/.test(loc)) {
                $('#home').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/about/.test(loc)) {
                $('#about').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/accommodation/.test(loc)) {
                $('#accommodation').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/gallery/.test(loc)) {
                $('#gallery').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/tariff/.test(loc)) {
                $('#tariff').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/facilities/.test(loc)) {
                $('#facilities').addClass('active');
            }
            if (/contact/.test(loc)) {
                $('#contact').addClass('active');
            }
        });
</script>
```

site where i used this one http://rtshotel.in/

change it with your code

Comment: I will try the first solution. The second one isn't really an option because I use content management system. I would need modify that script every time someone creates a new page.

Comment: @Sahil Popli a little bit offtopic, do you have any idea how can I solve this similar issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687806/how-to-keep-the-menu-state-on-page-reload thanks